# IntelliJ IDEA 12 - Incompatible Android version error

Tags: java, android, configuration, sdk, intellij-idea

I'm starting out Android development with IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.
I have installed and configured JDK and Android SDK.   I wanted to target Android SDK 2.3.3 so the SDK is configured as in the screenshot.

When I try and run the project though, I'm getting the following error:

```
android-validator: [untitled] Incompatible version of Android SDK Platform-tools package. Min version is 11. Please, update it though SDK manager
```

Followed by

```
android-validator: [untitled] Incompatible version of Android SDK Tools package. Min version is 19. Please, update it though SDK manager
```

I wasn't able to find any information on this and not sure what this means.  Any pointers is appreciated.

--New project config--
[image: New project config]

--Install Android Packages--
[image]

Comment: Why don't you update `Android SDK Tools` and `Android SDK Platform-tools`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> android-validator: [untitled] Incompatible version of Android SDK
>   Platform-tools package. Min version is 11. Please, update it though
>   SDK manager

Because you have revision 10 and the IntelliJ IDEA tool needs revision 11

> android-validator: [untitled] Incompatible version of Android SDK
>   Tools package. Min version is 19. Please, update it though SDK manager

Because you have revision 16 and the IntelliJ IDEA tool needs revision 19

The mentioned minimal revisions are requirements for IntelliJ IDEA to provide Android tools and to compile your applications. You should definitly launch again the Android SDK Manager and check the Tools folder, as on your screenshot, and click on "Install 2 packages".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I updated "Android SDK Platform-tools" but it didn't work.
After that I realized that in the past I set **c:\Android\android-sdk** as the SDK folder. But the SDK manager was updating the folder named **c:\Documents and Settings\my.user\Local Settings\Application Data\Android\android-sdk** So IntelliJ was checking the old folder.

Problem solved after changing to right folder. So be sure that you set new folder if you have such issue. Check help documentation for setting the SDK folders: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html